# Disable a whole function when window size is below 770px

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would I do to Disable the whole following Function when the window size is below 770px? and Enable it again when the screen size is above 770px... Can we do it using JavaScript it self?

**Here is the whole function / code / snippet that need to be Disabled:**

```
//Sticky Box //
$(function () {
    $.fn.scrollBottom = function () {
        return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height();
    };

    var $StickyBox = $('.detailsBox');
    var $window = $(window);

    $window.bind("scroll resize", function () {
        var gap = $window.height() - $StickyBox.height() - 10;
        var visibleFoot = 255 - $window.scrollBottom();
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop < 50) {
            $StickyBox.css({
                top: (130 - scrollTop) + "px",
                bottom: "auto"
            });
        } else if (visibleFoot > gap - 100) {
            $StickyBox.css({
                top: "auto",
                bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
            });
        } else {
            $StickyBox.css({
                top: 80,
                bottom: "auto"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The whole code above, isn't that called function? sorry I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a flag to keepTrack of the window size (I see you're using jQuery, so I assume it is loaded):

```
var smallScreen = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    smallScreen = $(window).width() < 770;
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    smallScreen = $(window).width() < 770;
});
```

And then use it when you call your function:

```
function doSomething() {
    if(smallScreen) {
        //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: I just swapped, I though you wanted it disabled Over 777, anyway, this shoud work: http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/uKw8Q/2/

Comment: How would i use for my function? as it's not working for me, sorry I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fire the function when the page loads, and when someone resizes the screen above 770px;

```
// Fire when the page loads
stickyBox();

// Fire on page resize
$(window).resize(stickyBox);

// Our function
function stickyBox() {

    if($(window).width() > 770) {

        $.fn.scrollBottom = function () {
            return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height();
        };

        var $StickyBox = $('.detailsBox');
        var $window = $(window);

        $window.bind("scroll resize", function () {
            var gap = $window.height() - $StickyBox.height() - 10;
            var visibleFoot = 255 - $window.scrollBottom();
            var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

            if (scrollTop < 50) {
                $StickyBox.css({
                    top: (130 - scrollTop) + "px",
                    bottom: "auto"
                });
            } else if (visibleFoot > gap - 100) {
                $StickyBox.css({
                    top: "auto",
                    bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
                });
            } else {
                $StickyBox.css({
                    top: 80,
                    bottom: "auto"
                });
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make it on Re-size and without?

Comment: Sorry Leo, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: it works when you try to re-size the screen, but if you visited the website on that size it won't work unless you have re-sized the screen.

Comment: You might want to look at the 'Debouncing' function though, as in Webkit browsers, the resize functions fires multiple times as the user is resizing.  Debouncing it will set a timeout so it only fires once - http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to disable the callback to your resize and scroll event listener. You can do this by wrapping your logic in a test for the window height.

Note that `bind` has been deprecated, it's best to use `on()` instead. You should also be very careful with the scroll event. Here is a [good article](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/) on why and how to avoid the performance problems it can cause.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GK5jB/1/)**

```
$window.on("scroll resize", function () {
    if ($window.width() > 770) {
        var gap = $window.height() - $StickyBox.height() - 10;
        var visibleFoot = 255 - $window.scrollBottom();
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop < 50) {
            $StickyBox.css({
                top: (130 - scrollTop) + "px",
                bottom: "auto"
            });
        } else if (visibleFoot > gap - 100) {
            $StickyBox.css({
                top: "auto",
                bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
            });
        } else {
            $StickyBox.css({
                top: 80,
                bottom: "auto"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: for some reason this has disabled it from above 770 as well

Comment: hmm why are you using the Window hight? not width?

Comment: Sorry, you said "window size", I assumed you meant height. I updated to use widths.

Answer (score -1):

Use JQuery .width() and .height() functions to get the size of the window and then perform the operation needed.

```
$(window).width(); // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```