# React - Disable function when browser shrinks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to disable a onMouseEnter / onMouseLeave event listener when the browser window is shrinking below 600px for instance. My question relates to a similar query **[Disable a whole function when window size is below 770px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612727/disable-a-whole-function-when-window-size-is-below-770px/18612818)**. However, I've never used jquery, so I was wondering is there a way to achieve the same thing in React without using jquery.

This is the sample I am working on https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-rubin-vh2ft?file=/src/App.js:482-494

I would really appreciate any suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this on your project and it worked.

replace your handleMyPhoto method with this:

```
handleMyPhoto = () => {
    const showPhoto = window.innerWidth < 600 ? false : !this.state.showPhoto;
    this.setState({ showPhoto  });
};
```

This basically checks if the window width is less than 600px then it sets showPhoto state to false, otherwise it revert the existing state as normal.